# How to make all the code in a try block run before the catch statement executes

Tags: c#

I have to try to instantiate three objects, two of them are going to throw exceptions but I want to make all the code in the try block run before the exception is thrown. Is there anyway to do this without using three different try blocks?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Employee EmPy1 = new Employee("111-11-111", -4.0);
            Employee EmPy2 = new Employee("222-22-222", 7.5);
            Employee EmPy3 = new Employee("333-33-333", 750);
        }
        catch (EmployeeException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

class Employee
{
    private string _id;
    private double _hourlyWage;
    public double HourlyWage
    {
        get { return _hourlyWage; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 255)
            {
             throw new EmployeeException("Value must be greater than 0 and less than 254");   
            }
            else
            {
                _hourlyWage = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public Employee(string Id, double hourlyWage)
    {
        _id = Id;
        HourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could use Visual Basic and `On Error Resume Next`, though I would not recommend it. Seriously: you need three try/catch blocks for what you want to do.

Comment: Simple answer no, it might be possible using tasks but will add complexities. What you could do is catch the error internally within your Employee object and then check to see if any errors had been thrown and then return those errors back as some form of combined error stack.

Comment: You will notice from the answers so far that the problem is that you are using three separate variables: `EmPy1`, `EmPy2`, `EmPy3`. If you had a list of `EmPy` then you could iterate over them and collate the exceptions (if any) into a list of exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to write less code, you can encapsulate it in a function

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee EmPy1 = TryCreateCmployee("111-11-111", -4.0);
        Employee EmPy2 = TryCreateCmployee("222-22-222", 7.5);
        Employee EmPy3 = TryCreateCmployee("333-33-333", 750);
    }

    static Employee TryCreateCmployee(string id, double hourlyWage)
    {
        try
        {
            return new Employee(id, hourlyWage);
        }
        catch (EmployeeException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you are missing a return null at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I think I will implement something like this into my code.

Answer (score 7):

`Is there anyway to do this without using three different try blocks?`

No.

The whole point of the `catch` is to handle any exception that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapper(/* have your ids-salarys here as a tupel */)
    }
}

public Tuple(List<Employee>,List<Exception>) Builder(string anId, double aSalary){

    Employee EmPy = new Employee(anId,aSalary);
}

public Tuple(List<Employee>,List<Exception>) Wrapper(IEnumerable<Tuple<string,double> aTuple){
    var employees = new List<Employee>();
    var exceptions = new List<Excetpion>();

    foreach (var t in aTuple){
       try
        {
             Builder(t.First,t.Second);
             employees.Add(EmPy);
        }
        catch (EmployeeException ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(ex)
        } 
    }
}

class Employee
{
    // snip snip
}
```

Now you have one try catch, but you reuse it :)

Do note that this was written in a text pad, and syntax was from memory. If it complains, you might need to tweak the Tuple maybe ... but it should be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the problem a little bit differently and separate them to another method. The failed Employee ids could be stored in a list, and as with the successfully created employees. You can then process them later.

Here is one way you could do it

```
class MyProgram
{
    private static List<string> _failedEmployeeIds;

    private static List<Employee> _successfullyCreatedEmployees;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _failedEmployeeIds = new List<string>();
        _successfullyCreatedEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        TryCreateEmployee("111-11-111", -4.0);
        TryCreateEmployee("222-22-222", 7.5);
        TryCreateEmployee("333-33-333", 750);

        ProcessFailedEmployees(); // do something here
        ProcessCreatedEmployees(); // do something here
    }

    static void TryCreateEmployee(string employeeId, double employeeWage)
    {            
        try
        {
            var employee = new Employee(employeeId, employeeWage);
            _successfullyCreatedEmployees.Add(employee);
        }
        catch (EmployeeException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            _failedEmployeeIds.Add(employeeId);
        }
    }
}

class Employee
{
    private string _id;
    private double _hourlyWage;
    public double HourlyWage
    {
        get { return _hourlyWage; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 255)
            {
                throw new EmployeeException("Value must be greater than 0 and less than 254");
            }

            _hourlyWage = value;
        }
    }
    public Employee(string Id, double hourlyWage)
    {
        _id = Id;
        HourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    }
}
```